# Are there any catches to shifting a graph?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If we have some function $f(x)$ defined on some interval $a<x<b$ and we shift it right by $x_0$ so that our new function is $f(x-x_0)$, are there any catches to doing this? Besides our interval changing to $a<x-x_0<b$

Would it cause things like differentiation or integration to not work anymore?

If we have say a solution to an nth order linear differential equation and we want to shift the solution to the right (used in electrical engineering) will the solution still be valid if we replace every instance of $x$ with $x-x_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a new variable $y=x-x_0$ and rewriting the problem in terms of $y$.  You are correct that you need to change the intervals of integration-you are doing what people call a $u$ substitution.  You have $f'(y)=f'(x-x_0)$ because (from the chain rule) $\frac {dy}{dx}=1$

Comment: If I had a linear ordinary differential equation, can I just do a substitution like above for the independent variable without changing anything?

Comment: @Jason: Try it, and don't forget the chain rule!

Comment: @CameronBuie It seems to work for linear functions with constant coefficients, which is really just what I was thinking about.  Thanks